# Verificar retorno ajax, funciona só na primeira vez

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Bom dia amigos, tenho esse código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var codigo = $(this).attr('id');            
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post', 
            url: '<?= base_url('posts/apaga'); ?>',
            data: 'codigo='+codigo,                
            success: function(msg){
                if(msg.indexOf("Erro") > -1){
                    $('#ret_apaga_post').html(msg);                        
                }else{
                    $('#reload_post').html(msg);
                }

            }
        });
    });
});
```

A situação é que tenho uma lista de dados retornados do banco, e tenho um botão exclui para cada registro.

O que acontece, é que dependendo do retorno `PHP`, preciso carregar em divs diferentes. Encontrei dicas sobre `msg.indexOf("Erro")`, sobre `jquery contains selector` e também `str.match(/Erro/)`, porém só funcionam na primeira vez.

Tentei também adicionar ao ajax `cache: false`, também sem sucesso.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Algumas boas práticas que defini como minhas regras com AJAX:

- Sempre envie dados através de um objeto não importa o tipo de requisição (GET/POST/PUT...)
- Trabalhe sempre com o retorno de dados em JSON

Com apenas esses dois itens, a url e tratando o retorno de sucesso, faço tudo!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var codigo = $(this).attr('id');            
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post', 
            url: '<?php echo base_url('posts/apaga'); ?>',
            data: {'codigo': codigo},  
            dataType: 'json'              
            success: function(msg){
                if (msg.erro) {
                    $('#ret_apaga_post').html(msg);                        
                } else {
                    $('#reload_post').html(msg);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

E agora o seu backend tem que devolver um tipo de dado em JSON, tente isso:

```
public function apaga() {
    $dados = array(
        'erro' => true,
        'mensagem' => 'Houve um erro :/'
    );
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($dados);
}
```

Comment: Ah! E eu aconselho evitar short tags com PHP, use `<?php echo` ao invés de `<?=`

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela ajuda, pelo que vi, seu código funciona sim, mas não foi necessário. Acabei de perceber que meu código está correto. Meu erro foi que eu estava alterando o `DOM` e sem utilizar `mutation observer` ou recaregar o `Jquery` na página, ele para de funcionar mesmo.

Comment: Perfeito, eu realmente não percebi que havia problemas, só não está seguindo o padrão que eu recomendo, mas não é por isso que não funcionaria :)

Comment: Você tem algum alternativa ao `mutation observer`? Eu acho o código muito grande e nem tive vontade de usar, no momento eu opto por sempre **recarregar o javascript** na página, mas parece gambiarra né.

Comment: AH! Obrigado por compartilhar isso sobre o `mutation observer` eu sempre tive esse tipo de problema que não está muito claro na pergunta (ou eu que não funciono bem pela manhã kkk), mas eu entendi. Diga mais como resolveu seu problema, vai ajudar muiiiito!!

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo mais detalhado do problema, na verdade o código na pergunta está correto, o problema é que ao recarregar via `ajax` parte do `DOM`, esse novo **pedaço de código** continua invisível para o `jquery` que acabou de ser usado.

Para nao usar o bendito `mutation observer`, eu prefiro dar `reload` no jquery, exemplo:

`<div id='div_reload_sempre'>
    <input type='text' value='pode ser apagado 1'>
    <button id='id_input_1'>1</button>
    <br>
    <input type='text' value='pode ser apagado 2'>
    <button id='id_input_2'>2</button>
</div>`

```
//essa div acima, tem uma cópia exata apenas do conteudo dela em outro arquivo `php` por exemplo com nome `conteudo_div_reload`
```

`<div id='recarrega_este_js'>
   <script>
    $('button').on('click',function()){
        //aqui vão parametros ajax normal como na pergunta
        success: function(msg){
            $('#div_reload_sempre').html('conteudo_div_reload');
            //aqui acima, vai recarregar a div, com os dados que ficaram apos o delete, ou seja la o que fizerem
            $('#recarrega_este_js').html('conteudo_desse_script');
            //aqui acima, esse jquery tem de ser recarregado após o delete feito, senao no proximo botão que for clicado, pro jquery, ele não existe mais
        }
    }
 </script>
</div>`

```
//mesma coisa para o script, tem de ter um outro arquivo com esse conteúdo nele
//nesse caso eu salvo esse conteudo dentro de um arquivo `php` mesmo, achei mais prático que um `js` por causa do framework que uso
```